# IIS 8.5 not working with ARR to route requests to Tomcat 8

Tags: windows-server-2012, tomcat8, iis-8.5, arr

I have using windows server 2012R2 to host a website in IIS 8.5 and I want to redirect request in a certain URL (e.g. /examples/) to the Tomcat 8.0 server hosted in same machine in port 8080.
I have tried to do this using ARR 3.0 but it gives a 404 error when a request is made.(e.g. localhost/examples/)

```
exact error : HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

Can anyone provide a solution or better approch to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

finally solved the issue.
I was using ARR 3.0 for the URL rewriting. I uninstalled it and installed the ARR 2.5 with the hotfix file. now the URL rewriting works smoothly.
May be Issue was with ARR 3.0 and Server 2012 running iis 8.5.
Thanks.